# Outputting information using super and overwriting

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to get the right total sales output, I keep on getting 0.0 instead of the appropriate 400 and 950 for the first and second employee.

I think my problem is in the Commission class with the overwritten pay method

The overridden pay method in Commission must call the pay method from the parent class from Hourly to compute the pay for hours worked then add to that the pay from commission on sales(totals sales times the commission rate) The total sales should be reset to 0 after the payment is calculated. –

```
public class Commission extends Hourly
{
  double total_sales;
  double commission_rate;

  public Commission(String name, String address, String phone,
                    String soc_sec_number, double rate,double commission_rate)
  {
    super(  name,   address,   phone,
                      soc_sec_number,   rate);
    // set commission rate
     commission_rate = 0.02;
  }

  public void addSales (double sales)
  {
    total_sales += sales;

  }

  public double pay() 
  {
    double payment = super.pay();   // call the method of the parent
                                    // add other code
    payment = payment + (total_sales * commission_rate);

    total_sales = 0.0;

    return payment;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return super.toString() + "\nTotalSales: " + total_sales;
  }

}
```

Hourly, the parent class with the pay method

```
// ********************************************************************
// Hourly.java       Java Foundations
//
// Represents an employee that gets paid by the hour
// ********************************************************************

public class Hourly extends Employee
{
  private int hours_worked;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Constructor: Sets up this hourly employee using the specified information
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public Hourly(String name, String address, String phone,
                String soc_sec_number, double rate)
  {
    super(name, address, phone, soc_sec_number, rate);
    hours_worked = 0;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------
  // Adds the specified number of hours to this employee's
  // accumulated hours
  // -----------------------------------------------------
  public void addHours(int more_hours)
  {
    hours_worked += more_hours;
  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------
  // Computes and returns the pay for this hourly employee
  // -----------------------------------------------------
  public double pay()
  {
    double payment = pay_rate * hours_worked;

    hours_worked = 0;
    return payment;
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns information about this hourly employee as a string
  // ----------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {
    return super.toString() + "\nCurrent hours: " + hours_worked;
  }
}
```

and staff where all the information is stored

```
// ********************************************************************
// Staff.java       Java Foundations
//
// Represents the personnel staff of a particular business
// ********************************************************************

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Staff
{
  private static DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  private StaffMember[] staff_list =
                        {
                          new Executive ("Tony",        "123 Main Line",  "555-0469", "123-45-6789", 2423.07),
                          new Employee  ("Paulie",      "456 Off Line",   "555-0101", "987-65-4321", 1246.15),
                          new Employee  ("Vito",        "789 Off Rocker", "555-0000", "010-20-3040", 1169.23),
                          new Hourly    ("Michael",     "678 Fifth Ave.", "555-0690", "958-47-3625",   10.55),
                          new Volunteer ("Adrianna",    "987 Babe Blvd.", "555-8374"),
                          new Volunteer ("Benny",       "321 Dud Lane",   "555-7282"),
                          new Commission("Christopher", "345 Movie Lane", "555-3831", "302-48-3871",    6.25, 0.2),
                          new Commission("Bobby",       "61 Train St.",   "555-2869", "492-58-2956",    9.75, 0.15)
                        };

  // ----------------------------------
  // Constructor: Updates staff members
  // ----------------------------------
  public Staff()
  {
    ((Executive)staff_list[0]).awardBonus(500.00);

    ((Hourly)staff_list[3]).addHours(40);

    ((Commission)staff_list[6]).addHours(35);    // add commissioned employees
    ((Commission)staff_list[7]).addHours(40); 

  }

   // ----------------------
   // Pays all staff members
   // ----------------------
  public void payday()
  {
    double amount;

    for (int count=0; count < staff_list.length; count++)
    {
      System.out.println(staff_list[count]);
      amount = staff_list[count].pay();
      if (amount == 0.0)
        System.out.println("Thanks!");
      else
        System.out.println("Paid: " + fmt.format(amount));
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you do any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see your field `total_sales` being initialized in your Commission constructor.

Also, I am not sure what you mean by first and second employee, if you are referring to `staff_list[1]` and `staff_list[2]` they are Employee class so verify that the Employee constructor is being properly initialized, the only way I see them earning any money is if they have some hard-coded number being returned in the `Employee.pay()` method.